# Adjusting Kaplan curve in survival analysis

Tags: r, survival-analysis

```
library(survival)
library(ranger)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(ggfortify)


data(veteran)
km_fit <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ trt, data=veteran)
autoplot(km_fit)


km_fit <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ trt + age, data=veteran)
autoplot(km_fit)
```

How do you get adjusted KM curves? In this example when I add "age" to the survfit model I get this error:

**Error in `levels<-`(`*tmp*`, value = as.character(levels)) : 
  factor level [31] is duplicated**

So how do you estimate adjusted KM curves and plot them?

Comment: Try to giev an example dataset reproducing your error, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. This post could help: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/323310/survival-curve-for-cox-regression-of-multiple-imputated-data

Comment: I did. see above : data(veteran)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple methods to create confounder-adjusted survival curves. One great way to get an overview is the documentation of the `adjustedCurves`: https://github.com/RobinDenz1/adjustedCurves

It includes a lot of methods, examples and detailed documentation.